# Problem with an UV map (doubled mesh) and texture painting

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, subdivision-surface

I sculpted this head myself, I did retopology of it and I marked seams to make a nice and readable UV map. Then I subdivided it, because I want to keep it detailed.

[image: Screenshot of my mesh 1]
[image: Screenshot of my mesh 2 with visible vertices]

When I unwrap the mesh, I get a UV map with my mesh, but doubled. It could be harmless, but it gives me a lot of problems while trying to texture paint, since it looks like I need to paint on two layers of the same mesh (if that makes sense), if i don't, it will leave marks.

[image: Screenshot of the UV map of the mesh]

Here when I try to paint directly on my mesh. It's leaving the marks.

[image: Screenshot of Texture painting of my mesh]

Here when I paint on the UV map. One eye layer is painted.

[image: Screenshot of Texture painting of mesh. One eye layer painted.]

And here, when both eye layers are painted.

[image: Screenshot of Texture painting of mesh. Both eye layers painted.]

I've tried to Remove Doubles (Merge by Distance) and then unwrap again, it's still doubled but messier.

[image: Screenshot of the UV map after Removing Doubles]

I'm new to 3D design so I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double geometry overlapping. Deselect everything in edit mode and then select one copy of it by hitting L while hovering the mouse over it. Hit X to delete it. Redo UV unwrapping after that.

The mesh also looks way too dense for that amount of detail...

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help! Your technique didn't work forme but I've looked up how to remove double geometry overlapping and it gave me an idea. In Edit Mode I clicked Select > Select All by Trait > Interior Faces. It showed me that second layer I couldn't see before and I deleted it. Unwrapping went well this time, so I think the problem is solved. Thank you again.

Comment: What do you mean "Your technique didn't work for me"? What can be not working in hitting A 2 times and then L while hovering over some edge or vert or face and then X? Of course there are plenty of good ways to remove double geometry, but Selecting Linked with L is a useful function, you should learn to use it in any case.